# conflicting types for my function "inverse", which is designed to return long long type

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors, inverse, modular

I try to figure out what I did wrong here, basically the function is for calculating the module inverse number to a<sup>-1</sup> mod m. but program is getting errors.

can somebody point out what is causing the errors?

```
//calculating the inverse of the public key, for getting private key d. long     
long long inverse(long long a, long long m) 
{ 
   long long p = a, q = m, t; 
   //Euclidean algorithm 
   long long x = 0, y = 1, z = (long long)q/p; 

   //start recursion 
   while(p != 1 && q != 1) 
   {
       t = p; 
       p = q % p; 
       q = t; 
       t = y; 
       y = x - y * z; 
       x = t; 
       z = (long long)q/p; 
   } 

   y = (long long)y % m; 
   if(y < 0) 
   { 
      y += m; 
   } 

   //return inverse number; 
   return y; 
}
```

Comment: You probably didn't declare a prototype for `inverse()`. Declare it at the top of source file: `long long inverse(long long, long long);`

Comment: Don't post code as an image !! What is "getting errors" supposed to mean? Which errors ?

Comment: sorry about that, the exactly error: conflicting types for 'inverse'

Comment: at long long ^ inverse(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared a function prototype that doesn't match the function definition, example of how you can do that, put at the top of the file or in a header file the following

```
int inverse(int a, int n);
```

and then your definition is

```
long long inverse(long long a, long long n)
{
}
```

Comment: yeb, not proper declare, I am going to pass the base number and module number, return e^(-1) mod m

Comment: that was a error message, not warning, so the program now cant get compile, I guess some data type wrong cause this conflicting types to return, but cant figure it out

Comment: @Seven I am sorry I can't understand what you say, and you must post code that reproduces the problem, the code you posted doesn't.

Comment: I'm _linking_ my answer with yours,  hope that's ok with you. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh it's always ok, you don't need to tell me, I trust that your answer is correct.

Comment: You also got it right in the first place. I don't know why'd someone downvote your answer. I did the opposite. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is either of the below:

1. You have a **mismatched** forward declaration with the function definition, as mentioned rightly by Mr. *@iharob* in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30395951/2173917).
2. You **don't have** a forward declataion at all. The function has been used (called) **before** it has been defined. So, the implicit declaraion (`int` return, any number of argument acceptance) is conflicting with the actual definition.